# Drawable tinting in RecyclerView for pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use drawable tinting using the following code in my `RecyclerView`

```
Drawable likeDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_thumb_up);
Drawable likeWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(likeDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(likeWrappedDrawable,ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));
holder.ivLike.setImageDrawable(likeWrappedDrawable);
```

Now all of this is being done in the `onBindViewHolder` of the RecyclerView Adapter

I change this tint between three colors based on the state of that list item. This works all fine for Lolipop and above but below this version, the color of the list item is unpredictable. Sometimes it shows the right color but on refreshing the list sometimes it changes to some other color.

Anything im doing wrong here or the tinting thing on pre-lollipop is still unusable in this particular case?

### Update

Including the code from my `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Drawable likeDrawable =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_thumb_up);

    Drawable likeWrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(likeDrawable);

    holder.tvLikeCount.setTextColor(ResUtil.getColor(R.color.light_font,
        getActivity()));

    DrawableCompat.setTint(likeWrappedDrawable,
        ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));

    if (tweetModel.isFavorited()) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(likeWrappedDrawable,
            ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    }

    holder.ivLike.setImageDrawable(likeWrappedDrawable);

}
```

Comment: What kind of drawable is ic_thumb_up? Just a PNG, or an XML-based drawable?

Comment: Can we have the full code of `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: Will post the code today

Comment: Updated my question with the requested code. Sadly I am not in a position to share more than this

Comment: You can try my answer from the link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499495/dynamically-tint-drawable-in-adapter-change-color-for-all/63283675#63283675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499495/dynamically-tint-drawable-in-adapter-change-color-for-all/63283675#63283675)

Comment: [You can check with my answer, just give it a try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499495/dynamically-tint-drawable-in-adapter-change-color-for-all/63283675#63283675)

Answer (score 12):

Call mutate() on the Drawable before calling setTint()

```
Drawable likeDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_thumb_up).mutate();
```

By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()

Comment: I tried using it last time but didnt helped much. Will give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR.** If you're worried about efficiency, use [`TintedIconCache`](https://gist.github.com/AnixPasBesoin/1b29fc61c85698526ab902974f7c0aa1), a single class you can grab from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AnixPasBesoin/1b29fc61c85698526ab902974f7c0aa1).

```
TintedIconCache cache = TintedIconCache.getInstance();
Drawable myTintedDrawable = cache.fetchTintedIcon(context, R.drawable.icon_01, R.color.color_01));
```

### The need to do more than just `.mutate()`

As @Vladimir stated, you have to call `drawable.mutate()` to get an isolated state, otherwise any change made to your drawable properties would be reflected on all the other drawables sharing the same state.

This behavior is actually meant for good reasons, one of which is memory efficiency, and there are some scenarios where you'd want to keep that efficiency.

For instance, you might have a `RecyclerView` with items using the same drawable but tinted differently for each item according to some property (e.g. success, failure, warning, info, etc). If you're in that case, mutating your drawable for each item is not the best solution. You could think of creating all the possible drawables, with all the possible tints, but you might be creating useless onces. If you're in that case, I got you covered!

### Enters `TintedIconCache`

A better solution is have some sort of drawable cache, where each uniquely tinted drawable is created only when needed, and then is cached efficiently for subsequent needs until you no longer need it or the system wants that occupied memory back.

I have already implemented this, in [`TintedIconCache`](https://gist.github.com/AnixPasBesoin/1b29fc61c85698526ab902974f7c0aa1). It's straightforward to use:

```
// Get an instance
TintedIconCache cache = TintedIconCache.getInstance();

// Will be fetched from the resources
Drawable backIcon = cache.fetchTintedIcon(context, R.drawable.icon, R.color.black));

// Will be fetched from the resources as well
Drawable bleuIcon = cache.fetchTintedIcon(context, R.drawable.icon, R.color.bleu));
   
// Will be fetched from the cache!!!
Drawable backIconTwo = cache.fetchTintedIcon(context, R.drawable.icon, R.color.back));
```

---

Consider looking at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/AnixPasBesoin/1b29fc61c85698526ab902974f7c0aa1) to see how it works under the hood.