# Dynamically Tint drawable in adapter change color for all

Tags: android, imageview, adapter, drawable, android-viewholder

I get an array of strings from my server using a volley connection. Every single string contain a different color in hex. I use this color to set Tint of a drawable in adapter.

Here my code in adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // Get item from position
    MyObject object = array_data.get(position);
    ...
    ...
    Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_beenhere_black_24dp);
    Drawable wrappedDrawable;
    if (unwrappedDrawable != null) {
        wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, object.getMyColor());
        holder.imvPreparationTime.setImageDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
    }
```

Unfortunately the behavior is not correct. All drawable of items in recyclerview have the same color together and it change for all during scroll.

[image]

How can I perform my goal? I want that every items have his own color and not change.

Comment: This post cointains the answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944501/changing-color-of-single-drawable-in-recyclerview-will-change-all-drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944501/changing-color-of-single-drawable-in-recyclerview-will-change-all-drawables)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `Drawable.mutate()` . In your adapter class, onBindViewHolder(..) block, use below code snippet to change the tint color of your drawable -

```
for (Drawable drawable : myTextView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()) {
                    if (drawable != null) {
                        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                        Drawable mutableDrawable = wrappedDrawable.mutate();
                        DrawableCompat.setTint(mutableDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.desiredColor));
                    }
                }
```

Note : This code snippet I've used to change the tint of textview's drawable. So, if you required to change the tint of image or drawable file, simply do it as :

```
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                        Drawable mutableDrawable = wrappedDrawable.mutate();
                        DrawableCompat.setTint(mutableDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrayD5));
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I had this problem and your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since recyclerView is reusing items there is often such a behaviour. Easiest way is to put if else for view you want to set tint for.
E.g.

```
if (unwrappedDrawable != null) {
        wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, object.getMyColor());
        holder.imvPreparationTime.setImageDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
    } else {
        holder.imvPreparationTime.setImageDrawable(<Some Other drawable, for example default one>);
    }
```

The idea is to force recycler view draw something on item and not to reuse already set one.

Comment: I try this code, but the behaivor is the same of the previous. Why you tell me to set the else for 'if (unwrappedDrawable != null)' ? This conditions is already true because 'of Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_beenhere_black_24dp);' line.